# What does this funnelweb command mean in visual studio? and why did it exit with 4?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, model-view-controller, funnelweb

In visual studio on the post build event command line I have the following:

```
 xcopy $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)FunnelWeb.Web\bin\Extensions\ /Y
```

and its creating the error:

> ```
> Error 1   The command "xcopy C:\Users\Exitos\Desktop\FunnelWeb-2.0.2.572-source\src\FunnelWeb.Extensions.MetaWeblog\bin\Debug\FunnelWeb.Extensions.MetaWeblog.dll
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Exitos\Desktop\FunnelWeb-2.0.2.572-source\src\FunnelWeb.Web\bin\Extensions\
>   /Y
>       xcopy C:\Users\Exitos\Desktop\FunnelWeb-2.0.2.572-source\src\FunnelWeb.Extensions.MetaWeblog\bin\Debug\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll
>   C:\Users\Exitos\Desktop\FunnelWeb-2.0.2.572-source\src\FunnelWeb.Web\bin\Extensions\
>   /Y" exited with code 4.   FunnelWeb.Extensions.MetaWeblog

Im confused as to where the $(TargetPath) and $(SolutionDir) are set, and why this error happened?

Answer (score 0):

xcopy exit codes can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true

I suspect the problem is that you need double quotes around your paths:

```
xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)FunnelWeb.Web\bin\Extensions" /Y
```

Becouse of spaces inside your path.

When you open a .sln, `$(SolutionDir)` is the directory where it came from. If you
 want to change it, move the root folder for your .sln file.

Hope it helps.